# GLPK Integer Optimizer prints "PROBLEX HAS NO INTEGER FEASIBLE SOLUTION" but still returns optimal status

Tags: python, linear-programming, convex-optimization

Help needed with the output of GLPK. 
Some constraints cannot be met (intentionally) 
GLPK prints "PROBLEM HAS NO INTEGER FEASIBLE SOLUTION" 
but still returns 'optimal' as the status of the solution.

I've set all tolerance levels to 0

```
glpk.options['feastol']=0
solvers.options['feastol']=0
glpk.options['abstol']=0
solvers.options['abstol']=0        
glpk.options['reltol']=0
solvers.options['reltol']=0
```

This is the output

```
   GLPK Integer Optimizer, v4.43
   10 rows, 5 columns, 19 non-zeros
   5 integer variables, none of which are binary
   Preprocessing...
   1 hidden covering inequaliti(es) were detected
   5 rows, 5 columns, 14 non-zeros
   5 integer variables, all of which are binary
   Scaling...
    A: min|aij| =  1.000e+00  max|aij| =  1.000e+00  ratio =  1.000e+00
   Problem data seem to be well scaled
   Constructing initial basis...
   Size of triangular part = 4
   Solving LP relaxation...
   GLPK Simplex Optimizer, v4.43
   5 rows, 5 columns, 14 non-zeros
         0: obj =   2.000000000e+00  infeas =  1.000e+00 (1)
   *     2: obj =  -2.500000000e+00  infeas =  0.000e+00 (0)
   *     3: obj =  -4.000000000e+00  infeas =  0.000e+00 (0)
   OPTIMAL SOLUTION FOUND
   Integer optimization begins...
   +     3: mip =     not found yet >=              -inf        (1; 0)
   +     3: mip =     not found yet >=     tree is empty        (0; 1)
   PROBLEM HAS NO INTEGER FEASIBLE SOLUTION
```

The wanted behavior is to indicate failure when "PROBLEM HAS NO INTEGER FEASIBLE SOLUTION"

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I only know the C API but I guess you can easily figure out the Python equivalent.

In the C API you use `glp_mip_status()` and you would get `GLP_NOFEAS` in your case, meaning that the "problem has no integer feasible solution". See under *determine status of MIP solution* in the doc.

I wouldn't mess with the tolerances.

Comment: Is that an "option" (like 'reltol') ?

Comment: Oops, sorry, forgot to add the brackets. It is a function call, and you call it after the solve has finished. Then it returns the MIP status.

Comment: It seems I do not have a function like that. 
The only available items from this package are:  

**dir(glpk)**
['__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'ilp', 'lp', 'options']

Comment: BTW, I've worked around it, but maybe others can benefit from an answer to it.

Comment: I would be really really surprised if this function wasn't available. I would look into `ilp` which, I guess, refers to integer programming. I don't know Python and in particular the API you are using so unfortunately I cannot help you with that.